# R plot.msets color code - is it possible to have multiple colors?

Tags: r, visualization, data-visualization, intersection, multiset

i'm using R to visualise multi set intersections, and that's how i found the SuperExactTest package.

My code is the following:

```
require(SuperExactTest)
data(Cancer)
Result1 = supertest(Cancer, n=20687)
plot(Result1, degree=2:3, legend.col=2, sort.by='size')
```

An there is the output:

[image: Plot1]

I try to color the seven categories with different colors like that:

```
require(SuperExactTest)
data(Cancer)
Result1 = supertest(Cancer, n=20687)
plot(Result1, degree=2:3, legend.col=2, sort.by='size', color.on = c("red","green","yellow","blue","orange","grey","pink"))
```

But the output shows only the first color of the list:

[image: Plot2]

Is it possible to use different colors in case of different categories?
Thanks for the help! :)